# Array DateTime.Date Compatibility with Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, linq-to-entities

I'm implementing a simple search. Right now, I can search through the posts using the terms in string array Split but I want to search the date aswell. So, I added an array of datetime. The problem I'm having is I only want to search the Date part of datetime, and ignore Time. Whenever I search, I get an error at d.Date.

```
 IEnumerable<Post> posts = from p in post_repository.Posts 
                           from s in split 
                           from d in Date
                           where (p.Title.Contains(s) || p.ContactPhone.Contains(s) || p.Content.Contains(s) || p.Author.Contains(s) || p.ContactEmail.Contains(s)|| **p.EndDate.Date.Equals(d.Date)**) && p.Deleted == false && p.Publish == true 
                           select p;
```

Error Message:

```
The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.


Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

I've been stuck at this for a while, can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong?
All the dates are initialized, so there is nothing null and everything other than date works. If I remove d.Date or EndDate.Date, there is no error but I dont get the desired result.
Thanks in Advance.

Edit 1:

```
string[] split = query.Split(breakpoints);
DateTime[] arrayOfDateTimes = Datify(split);
```

The Declaration might seem really stupid. Datify is a function I wrote which returns an array of DateTime which works properly cause I went through it step by step looking at the local variables.

```
private readonly char[] breakpoints = {'.', ',', ' ', ':', '\t' };
```

Query is the search, its a string.

Comment: Can you split apart what you think your query is doing?  And giving us a declaration of what `split` and `Date` are would help too.  As is, those second and third `from` expressions look wrong.

Comment: DateTime: 10/10/2010 12:36:...., Date would be 10/10/2010 part of datetime.
I'll try to split it apart and write how it goes.

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory 
Cause of you comment I finally figured it out. Instead of Date, I used Day, Month and Year.

Answer (score 1):

Use the class **EntityFunction** for trimming the time portion.

using System.Data.Objects;

EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(EndDate)